# Read Parquet files directly while using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, parquet, postgres-fdw

I am trying to install an extension to postgres that will help me write postgres queries to read data directly from parquet files.
This is the extension I found - https://github.com/pgspider/parquet_s3_fdw

After installing the required dependencies I went ahead and tried running the 'make' command.

```
make install
```

But ends up with an error

```
Makefile:45: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

Has anyone else tried using this extension ? Or can you suggest me some other way to read data directly from parquet files while using postgres ? (Please note: conversion from parquet to any other format is not allowed under the circumstances that I'm trying this)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the error there but the FDW you referenced is for accessing parquet files on S3 which you didn't mention as a requirement. You might want to try a simpler version like https://github.com/adjust/parquet_fdw

Answer (score 0):

For reference see the answers to Patel's question here: https://github.com/pgspider/parquet_s3_fdw/issues/7

Long story short, the solution is to append `USE_PGXS=1` to the `make install` command:

```
$ make install USE_PGXS=1
```